# iterating interface array using *ngFor in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, ngfor

So I have Implemented an interface for retrieve data from a service class.

```
export interface FilteredSubjects {
  key: string,
  list: Subject[]
}
```

So currently I want to iterate `FilteredSubject` interface array. So I check using `console.log`

[console log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL9en.jpg)

But I am unable to iterate this using *ngFor.
This is what I have tried so far. here `selectedStreamList`  values shows in interface `Key` attribute

**html**

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" *ngFor="let stream of selectedStreamList; let indexOfelement = index;">
<div class="class=pl-5">
  <table class="table table-borderless ">
    <tbody>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let subject of getStreamFilter(indexOfelement)">
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">  <mat-checkbox  (change)="toggle(subject)"> {{subject.name}} </mat-checkbox></th>
        <td><a (click)="openDeleteSubjectDialog(subject.id)">
          <mat-icon class="aligned-with-icon" color="warn">delete</mat-icon>
        </a></td>
      </tr>

    </ng-container>
  .....
```

this **Ts** method. I'm getting filteredlist from a parent component.

```
 @Input("slist") filteredlist: FilteredSubjects[];



 constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {}


getStreamFilter(index:number) : Subject[]{
    return this.filteredlist[index].list;
}
```

but this no working. how to solve this problem?

this is the error 
[image]

Comment: Where do you initialize the ```filteredlist```, it is undefined as it sits so ```filteredlist[index] ``` will be undefined thus causing the ngFor to terminate

Comment: i'm getting that from a parent component. I have updated the question with that :)

Comment: @PasinduSenarath Can you recreate the *problem* with a *simple* example in Stackblitz?

Comment: how did you passed the input property from parent: if you passed the input like this [slist]="x" where x is list of values. it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a way to solve this. it was a problem in calling method.

```
 getStreamFilterX(index:number) : Subject[]{

this.selectedStreamID = index;
let subList: Subject[] = [];
this.filteredlist.forEach((item: FilteredSubjects) => {
  if(item.key == index.toString()) {
    subList = item.list;
  }
});
return subList;
```